# I am trying to provide a single uniform theme to the whole app, but it is giving error

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I am trying to apply an uniform theme of background color to my app but it is giving this error and I am not able to resolve it.
[This is the link to the error image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6HdE.png)

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: From further onwards I will keep this in mind. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding scaffold to the container on the second page

```
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
     import 'package:flutter/services.dart'

     void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData( brightness: Brightness.light,
         primaryColor: Colors.white,
         scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,),
     home: Scaffold(
         backgroundColor: Colors.white,
         body: Application(),
     ),
     ));
      class Application extends StatelessWidget {
      const Application({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(body:
       Container(
       ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove **const** from material app

```
 MaterialApp(
      home: MyAppBarWidget(),
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark, primaryColor: Colors.white),
    );
```

Comment: will this give a same background color to the app in every page?

Comment: No, it's your app theme color. when you set the background color you can put inside scaffold background color